# One Click; Divs Open In Opposite Direction

Tags: jquery, css, html, onclick

I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve this effect in JQuery.  A stackoverflow user recently help me achieving the effect I was going for; now I want to do it using JQuery and in the most efficient way possible.  Here's a link to the fiddle for a better explanation of what I'm looking to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/itsbc/U3Lg9/11/

The current version runs a bit choppy.  I'm looking for something a bit smoother, such as this:

http://jsfiddle.net/itsbc/QchfJ/

Thanks in advance, Bc.

Comment: why add jQuery bloat to something that doesn't need it?

Comment: Why do you want to do it in jQuery if you already have it working in js?

Comment: Well, I figured it would run a bit smoother if the code could be simplified.  Sorry, I updated the original post.  Thanks for such quick responses.

Comment: since your code is NOT using jQuery, it's already simpler. Adding the jQuery library could simplify the call, but it requires jQuery (ie: more code)... you know what I mean?

Comment: Yeah, but the website I'm wanting to integrate this into will be using the JQuery library already, so when all is said and done by simplifying the call, it will be using less code.

Comment: this is a good post, don't take the questions and argument about jquery use as an insult, merely an attempt to understand the decision you made.  +1-ed.  You not only presented your question clearly, but you also provided the work you'd done in a clear and concise format.

Comment: I agree with @deltree... definitely not trying to insult, just understand.

Comment: Their point is that you may be shortening the code visible to you but it is still more complex as it has to use the jQuery libraries. Visually it appears as if there is less code but overall it is using more code behind the scenes.

Comment: I "personally" would put that functioning code into a namespace and run it from an external lib. Then you don't have to worry about it bloating your html. For the jQuery part, I "might" use jquery to call the method instead of using `onclick`.

Comment: Deltree:  No offense taken.  I'm happy to see people are interested in helping in such a quick manner.  Thanks a lot for the +1.  Right back at you.  Tony318: I completely understand what you're saying.  I do like the control over the interval that jquery allows.  Gives it a much smoother appearance.  Chase Florell:  Same thing as Deltree.  I appreciate the input and trying to help me find an efficient way in such quick time.

Answer (score 1):

As other suggested in the comment section, you are better off with what you have in performance aspect.. If it is just slide animation.. you should simply stick to what you have..

However what you really want is `slideDown animation + hide effect`. Usually slideDown animation is to show element.. so you need to do a little trick to get this working.. See below,

**CSS:**

```
#hider1 { 
   position:fixed; /* Changed style*/
   top: 0px;       
   background: black;
   width:100%;
   height:48%;
   min-height:0px;
   text-align:center;
   color:white; 
}

#hider2 { 
   background-color:black;
   width:100%;
   height:50%;
   text-align:center;
   position:fixed;  /* Changed style*/
   bottom:0;        /* Changed style*/
   color:white; 
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#test').on('click', function () {
        $('#hider1').animate({            
            height: 0,
            opacity: 0.2 //<-- Fancy stuff
         },1000 );

        $('#hider2').animate({            
            height: 0,
            opacity: 0.2 //<-- Fancy stuff
         },1000 );

    });
});
```

​
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/U3Lg9/19/)** -> Verified in FF and Chrome.

Comment: Just checked out your demo, and while it works, it's not as smooth as the OP's raw JS version. There's a little "hiccup" on the bottom pain (at least in Chrome on OS X)

Comment: @ChaseFlorell It works out ok in firefox, but yea it fails in chrome as it starts off with `top: 0`. I need to check..

Comment: Can't wait for [requestAnimationFrame](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/05/requestAnimationFrame-API-now-with-sub-millisecond-precision)!!!

Comment: @ChaseFlorell Updated CSS and JS to make it work along.. However I am not sure if the OP wants this in full page.. as I am using `fixed` position

Comment: This appears to be working great.  I'm not sure I know enough about Javascript and JQuery to understand if this is the most effecient method, though.  Could anyone verify if this would be an efficient way to achieve this effect, or should I just go with the Javascript as Tony and I think Chase said?  +1'ing.  Will be back to mark as answer and/or respond.  Thanks for putting in the work and time, Vega.  Truly appreciated.

Comment: Looking at the [effects](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js) portion of the [jquery source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/), I think there is a lot more code being called versus using the vanilla code you posted.

Comment: If the rest of the site needs jQuery, then use it in the rest of the site. If your default page doesn't use jQuery for anything else other than the `open` bit, then loading jQuery on your initial page will slow down the UX.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I took your existing code and refactored it a little. The jQuery call will be as simple as this.

```
$("#opener").click(function() {
    myApp.websiteOpener.displayWebsite('hider1', 'hider2');
});
```

Then, from there you will have a separate file containing the required code.

```
var myApp = {};
myApp.websiteOpener = {

    up: null,
    down: null,
    topPanel: null,
    bottomPanel: null,

    displayWebsite: function(tPanel, bPanel) {
        if (typeof up !== "undefined") return;
        topPanel = tPanel;
        bottomPanel = bPanel;
        up = setInterval(this.goUp, 2);
        down = setInterval(this.goDown, 2);
    },

    goUp: function(x) {
        var h1 = document.getElementById(this.topPanel);
        if (h1.offsetHeight <= 0) {
            clearInterval(up);
            return;
        }
        h1.style.height = parseInt(h1.style.height) - 1 + "%";
    },

    goDown: function(x) {
        var h2 = document.getElementById(this.bottomPanel);
        if (h2.offsetHeight <= 0) {
            clearInterval(down);
            return;
        }
        h2.style.top = parseInt(h2.style.top) + 1 + "%";
        h2.style.height = parseInt(h2.style.height) - 1 + "%";
    }
};​
```

[Try it for yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/rockinthesixstring/QtNXH/)

Comment: Just got back to my computer.  Going to take a look at this and try to fully understand everything going on.  Thanks for taking the time to do this.  Will get back and mark as answer/respond.

Comment: Haha, this appears to be working just as well as the others.  Now it seems I've gotten so much help, I'm a little confused as to what the best option would be.  Thanks for putting in the time and effort on this.  Appreciate it.  Bc.

Comment: no problem. All I did was isolate your original code into a namespace (for cleanliness) and allowed you to use "minimal" jQuery without using all the bloat.

Answer (score 0):

Not using jQuery is likely to already be far more efficient than using it.

Perhaps the reason you really want to change it is to have more control over the animation (for example, over the speed or easing of the animation).  If that is the case, try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/U3Lg9/13/